# Inserting id into MYSQL table for multiple image upload(homestay)

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a form that creates an item in a database then in the next step it allows the user to upload multiple images for that listing both sections work on their own but i need to be able to insert the $id from the first page into the query for the image upload to identify which listing it corresponds to

Here is the page to allow the user to upload multiple images

```html
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="40" placeholder="Homestay's Name"/>
<input name="type" type="text" id="type" size="40" placeholder="Homestay's Type"/>
<input name="category" type="text" id="category" size="40" placeholder="Homestay's Category"/>
<input class='file' multiple="multiple" type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile[]" placeholder="Please choose your image">
```

here is the function

```php
 $path = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $i++)
    {
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $filetype = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $filesize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $destination = $path['dirname'] . '../data/' . $filename;
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $destination))
        {   


$name = $_POST['name'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$category = $_POST['category'];

 $sql="INSERT INTO homestay (name, type,category,)
VALUES
('$name', '$type','$category')";


        $result = mysql_query ("insert into img_homestay (id, location,filetype, filename, filesize)                                                
        values ('".$id."', '" . $destination . "','" . $filetype ."','" . $filename . "'," . $filesize . ") ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be :

- create the form to insert the db item
- get the ID of the inserted item, and add it as a hidden element on the second step
- once the second form gets back, you can easily see the ID you need.

Do note that this approach will send DB id's client side, but is the simplest option.

A second approach is to utilize session variables - simply store the item ID to the user session, and retrieve it on the second step. This is safer, but not a good approach if multiple forms can be submitted at the same time by the same account/person.

```
$_SESSION['the_id'] = $result->id;
```

and then

```
$id = $_SESSION['the_id'];
```

The best approach (in my opinion always) is to use a non-sensical token to the client side, and map it to the proper ID using some logic. A simple example is to generate a complex hash for the ID, and send that as a hidden field to the user when sending the form for step 2. Store the ID and hash in a database table.

When the user POSTs that back, use the hash to map it back to a normal ID, and destroy the entry.

Comment: but id will be auto increment for homestay table, and it will drag the id to the image table. but image table will be 0.

Comment: other than not using the deprecated `mysql_query`, there are ways to get the actual insert ID, and then using the above method.

Comment: what kind of ways? how do u suggest to solve my problem?

Comment: assuming you stick with `mysql_query`, you'll need `mysql_insert_id ()`

Comment: like this? $sql = "INSERT INTO homestay (name, type,category) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."', "
. "'".mysql_real_escape_string($type)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($category)."')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$id = mysql_insert_id();

but im still cannot insert id for image. id is to verify which one is for that homestay

Comment: after you insert into homestay, running `mysql_insert_id()` should return the id of the homestay row, which you can then use to insert  the image

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question:

In the previous page you have the id from the list.

At the second page, put it into a hidden field like:

```
<input type="hidde" name="theId" value="<?php echo $_POST["idFromPrevPage"]; ?>" />
```

And then you can access it from `$_POST["theId"]`

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, I think, you want to do something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO homestay (name, type,category) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."', "
. "'".mysql_real_escape_string($type)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($category)."')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$id = mysql_insert_id(); //This where you can get the last insert id.
```

**NOTES**

Anyway, you have several problems in your original code:

- In your first insert query have an unwanted `,` character at the field list.
- Do not use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli_* functions or PDO!
- Escape your data to avoid sql vulnerables or use prepared statements.

Comment: previous page only display a form. and the next page is the function insert to the different table like homestay table and img table. I need to get the value of $id into the database where the image is uploaded and its details stored in the database

Comment: still can not insert the $ id. homestay id is auto increment and img id is a foreign key. id function is where the image will be saved to the homestay. @lolka_bolka

this is my database :

homestay : id | name | type | category
img : no_img | id | filename | filesize | filetype | location